# Order of $xy$ in a group G

Tags: abstract-algebra, self-learning, cyclic-groups

I'm studying abstract algebra alone as my doctor needs a doctor haha. 
Ok, I'm studying about cyclic groups now.
I read that:

if 2 elements $x$ and $y$ commute in a group $G$, then the order of $xy$ is a divisor of $l.c.m(o(x),o(y))$,

then I read that it's exactly equal to $l.c.m(o(x),o(y))$, so got confused. 
Can anybody explain this to me? Also, can anybody advise me to read some detailed lectures about cyclic groups, as I feel like if I need much more to be strong at this lesson.

Comment: What if $y=x^{-1}$?

Comment: Then $xy=e$, and then the order of $xy$ is $1$.

Comment: And $1$ is probably not $\mathrm{lcm}(o(x),o(y))=o(x)$ where $o(x)$ denotes the order of $x$. Hmm, I presume you meant $\mathrm{lcm}(o(x),o(y))$ where you wrote $\mathrm{lcm}(x,y)$.

Comment: Yes I meant the orders not the elements. Sorry!! It has been a long day. I corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the answer which was accepted from the other post.

Comment: So you are telling me that $|xy|$ is exactly $lcm(x,y)$?  if $G$ has infinite order then the identity is the only element that has finite order which's $1$. Isn't right?

Comment: In the case where $xy=yx,$ yes. If $G$ has infinite order, there can still be things of finite order. Take, for example, $GL_2(\Bbb{R})$ the group of $2\times 2$ matrices with real entries. This group is infinite in order, and has many elements of infinite order, but there are elements of finite order. An example of an element of order $2.$
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc} 0&1 \\ 1&0 \end{array} \right)$$

Comment: Mmmm, I can conclude that in cyclic groups only, if $G$ has infinite order then its $non identity$ elements do. Ok so if the group in general is not abelian then $|xy|$ is a divisor of $lcm(|x|,|y|)$?

Comment: Yes the abelian condition is crucial. Another example is in the dihedral groups. Take the principle rotation, and multiply it by any reflection, it now has order 2.

Comment: Ok, you really made a difference. Thank you :)

Comment: No trouble at all! Would you mind clicking the check mark under my answer? An up vote wouldn't hurt either! :)

Comment: @Chickenmancer Part of what you say here is not correct. If $xy=yx$, $o(x)=n$, and $o(y)=m$, then it is not necessarily true that $o(xy)=lcm(n,m)$. For example, if $G=\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$, $x=1$, and $y=3$, then $o(x)=6$, $o(y)=2$, and $o(xy)=3$.

Comment: @Chickenmancer This is still incorrect. For example, if $G=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$, $x=(1,0)$ and $y=(0,1)$, then $o(x)=2$, $o(y)=3$, and $o(xy)=6$ (but $gcd(2,3)=1$). It is clear that $o(xy)$ always divides $lcm(o(x),o(y))$, but in general there are multiple possibilities for $o(xy)$.